# Visualise medium undirected graph in Java

Tags: java, graph, graph-visualization

I would like to visualise a medium-sized (up to 200000 nodes) undirected graph, preferably using a Java API. The API should allow labels for the edges (to show edge weight) and somehow visualise this edge weight (by colour or line thickness). Also, I would like to be able to save the result and it should be possible to run it on a single desktop computer. The graph will be static and I don't want to do any computations on it. Just look at it.

I tried JUNG (http://jung.sourceforge.net/) which I found very nice to use, but it does not seem to scale up to this size. Or at least not on my machine. Apart from the saving part (have not figured out yet whether this is possible or not) JUNG met all my requirements.

Then I had a look at Cassovary (https://github.com/twitter/cassovary), but it does not support undirected graphs and edge labels. Plus, it's not particularly well documented.

I hope you can point me towards an API that suits my needs better.

Comment: Have you tried http://prefuse.org? it allows labels for the edges. It is on GitHub.
(https://github.com/prefuse/Prefuse)

Comment: Do you know about running time and memory requirements? I had a look at their website, but didn't find anything like that. Did you use prefuse?

Comment: I have used both JUNG and Prefuse, but never with that many nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your help. For me on my computer, JUNG already fails with around 3000 nodes. (Or at least does not compute the graph within an hour.) I am trying out prefuse now.

Comment: I thank you for letting me know where the limits are... I use around 100 nodes for my project and had no problems with JUNG. I tried last week Prefuse with 3000 nodes with no problems and the results looked grahically better. I have the impression that Gephi (http://gephi.github.io/) will process huge graphs without trouble.